# date_query problem

Tags: wp-query, array, recent-posts

I'd like to get the closest post to today's post; yes, I checked and search this topic and found the code working for me:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Warsaw");
setlocale(LC_ALL, en_GB);
$year = strftime('%Y');
$month = strftime('%m');
$day = strftime('%e');
//$hour = strftime('%k');
if($month < 10)
{
    $month = substr($month,1);
}
$argsi = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'koncerty',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => array(
            'year' => $year,
            'month' => $month
            ),
        'inclusive' => 'true'
        )
    );
$recent_post = wp_get_recent_posts($argsi, ARRAY_A);
```

the problem is, when I'm trying to inlude the day to the array

```
$argsi = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'koncerty',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => array(
            'year' => $year,
            'month' => $month,
            'day' => $day
            ),
        'inclusive' => 'true'
        )
    );
```

the code stopped working and I don't know why. I tried `$day = strftime('%d')` and then remove 0 in it if day < 10, but still nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [**get_adjacent_post**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_adjacent_post/) function. This is a built-in wordpress function that you can use to get either the previous or next post from the current post.

**To get the next post:**

```
$next_post = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false, '' );
```

**To get the previous post:**

```
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post( false, '', true, '' );
```

You can also specify whether the post should be in the same taxonomy term and also set the taxonomy this is true.

> ```
> get_adjacent_post( bool $in_same_term = false, array|string $excluded_terms = '', bool $previous = true, string $taxonomy =
> ```
>
> 'category' )
>
> ### Parameters
>
> **$in_same_term**
>
> (bool) (Optional) Whether post should be in a same taxonomy term.
>
> *Default value: false*
>
> **$excluded_terms**
>
> (array|string) (Optional) Array or comma-separated list of excluded term IDs.
>
> *Default value: ''*
>
> **$previous**
>
> (bool) (Optional) Whether to retrieve previous post. Default true
>
> *Default value: true*
>
> **$taxonomy**
>
> (string) (Optional) Taxonomy, if $in_same_term is true.
>
> *Default value: 'category'*

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reply, but this function wasn't great for me. however I solved this - I forgotten I sorted the posts by post published date and my all "futured" posts had published date lower than 'today' but month was OK. I changed published date add to wp_query part to check also not published posts and now it works ;)